# Google Form Script User input grd row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When creating a grid question using Google Forms, how can I make the users input the rows?

On the second page of this form:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uPqAWB5lqEZpCX64E4LP-Mfg_FE3atdPgCMQ36OsoTM/viewform

There's Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, and Row 4.

How can I make Row 1, Row 2, etc. a user input field? Is it through the Form Script?

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting that a grid will behave like a spreadsheet (where cells are text input boxes), prepare to be disappointed.

Google Forms does not support this functionality, and Google Apps Script does not provide any Form items that are not already provided through the Forms UI.